# Redirecting www to non-www (just domain) over HTTPS in Azure

Tags: redirect, azure, https

I've got a site with SSL cert for just the domain itself (i.e. mydomain.com, instead of www.mydomain.com). I'm using the `RequireHttps` filter on my controller (ASP.NET MVC 4) and I have a host record at my domain provider that 301 redirects the `www` subdomain to `https://mydomain.com`.

So this is the result of the various combinations:

- mydomain.com => https://mydomain.com
- https://mydomain.com => same
- www.mydomain.com => https://mydomain.com
- https://www.mydomains.com => Timeout?

The last version, already over HTTPS, but with `www` fails to load for some reason. Any one know why?

Comment: Noone knows better than yourself. Try fiddler in combination with logs from 301 responses generated at your provider. I wonder why people still go through the hassle of redirecting when we have `pseudo-static` IP Address for our Azure Deployments. Do you know that the IP Address of an Azure Deployment will stay the same (will not change) as long as you don't `delete` this deployment. So having an `A Record` instead of `301 redirect` will work much better and safer. At the end indeed fiddler will give you the answer where exactly is the TimeOut - your provider times out for 301, or other issue.

Comment: The problem with the A record is that then www becomes equally as valid as just the domain, meaning your same site is available at two locations. I suppose any potential search penalty could be mitigated by using rel="canonical", but still.

Comment: interesting observation over SEO. Anyway, have you checked with fiddler what exactly happens when you try to load `https://www.mydomain.com/` ?

Comment: Yep. I tried and didn't get anything meaninful other than the connection being closed pretty much immediately after it was opened. It seems it has something to do with setting the 301 redirect at the host level, at least with my particular domain provider. I was able to resolve the issue by making www an A record as well and then manually redirecting in Global.asax. I really didn't want to do it that way, but it's more important that it just works.